# Nginx with sub locations

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, nginx, server

I'm trying to setup a dev server with nginx for two projects, one in rails and one in PHP. I want a base URL (dev.example.com) for both projects and a sub location for each one (dev.example.com/rails_proj and dev.example.com/php_proj). My nginx conf is like the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dev.example.com;

    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_app_env development;
    passenger_buffer_response off;
    root /var/www/dev;

    location ~ ^/rails_proj {
            root /public;
            passenger_base_uri /rails_proj;
            passenger_app_root /var/www/dev/rails_proj;
            passenger_document_root /var/www/dev/rails_proj/public;
    }

    location ~ ^/php_proj {
            root /web;
            try_files $uri /app_dev.php$is_args$args;

            location ~ \.php(/|$) {
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            }
    }
}
```

The rails project works fine but the PHP project gives me an "file not found" when I try to access dev.example.com/php_proj/app_dev.php and in the log It says: FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown". I found issues related to It and I've tried a number of ways but I can't come up with something that works for both projects. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to manage as two server blocks with an extra subdomain for each. It also reduces potential confusion introduced by multiple regex locations:

```
server {
    server_name rails.dev.example.com;
    return 200 "Hello from rails app.
";
}

server {
    server_name php.dev.example.com;
    return 200 "Hello from php app.
";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @putnamhil, I could use this as a temporary solution but by how my projects are organized I really preferred the url's in a sub location.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you've moved on or figured this out by now, but for posterity's sake: the root directive in your location block *overrides* your server root directive. It's not relative to it. The way you have your conf, the project files would need to be located in the absolute path /web/php_proj on your web server.

I can't quite determine the way your local paths are set up, but if  `/var/www/dev/rails_proj/public` is the directory that contains your app root, you may instead need to do something like this:

```
location /rails_proj {
    alias /var/www/dev/rails_proj/public;
}
```

Using alias instead of root will strip the /rails_proj from the beginning of the request path and serve files relative to the alias path. For example, if you request `http://dev.example.com/rails_proj/php/test.php`, it will serve the file `/var/www/dev/rails_proj/public/php/test.php`

Also, I would definitely recommend changing your top level location paths from regex to standard prefix paths. 
`location ~ ^/php_proj` is effectively identical to `location /php_proj` except that using regex messes with the way nginx decides what location to serve. Regex paths are more performance intensive, act on a first-match basis rather than best match, and will take priority over all prefix path locations.

Another thing to note: using `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name` may not always work as expected. Especially if using the alias directive instead of root. Using the variable `$request_filename` instead is preferable in most cases.